# GRUB on RHEL6.8 skips directly to rescue mode with "invalid arch independent elf magic"

Tags: rhel, grub

In my RHEL 6.8 installation GRUB seems to be corrupt. When I restart the server it is directly going to recue stage. Below message I am getting in virtual machine console:

```
error invalid arch independent elf magic
entering rescue mode
grub rescue
```

Do I need to attach same version of ISO image to reinstall GRUB? Actuall I have RHEL6.4 image only.

Answer (score 1):

An older image will most likely work.

Comment: mean if we can attach 6.9 will it work ?

Comment: 6.9 should work as well.